# How to set location or name auto fill in trip advisor widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

My problem is I have a lot of hotels lists on my website, but trip advisor widget only can get one. Any solution (example:script or what else) can use varible to set the location or name in widget automatically, it will auto search and display different hotel widget in the same code. Poor English hope your guys understand. Thank a lot.

```
<div id="TA_selfserveprop189" class="TA_selfserveprop">
<ul id="0DhvHbHb" class="TA_links wMTad7Z">
    <li id="BkwXZV" class="yr3LWVW09h">
    <a target="_blank" href="http://www.tripadvisor.com/"><img src="http://www.tripadvisor.com/img/cdsi/img2/branding/150_logo-11900-2.png" alt="TripAdvisor"/></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
<script src"http://www.jscache.com/wejs?wtype=selfserveprop&amp;uniq=189&amp;locationId=2701589&amp;
lang=en_US&amp;rating=true&amp;nreviews=5&amp;writereviewlink=true&amp;popIdx=true&amp;iswide=false&amp;border=true&amp;display_version=2"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

do u want to use auto complete to show a div like google search, you can use autocomplete addon of jquery.

I have implemented it many times, it is great for that purpose.

for reference use this example.http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jqueryui/jqueryui_autocomplete.htm

it also shows various example and documentation. 
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Hi Rohit , Actually I wan to display review for specific a hotel from tripadvisor. But I think different with this, by the way thank for answered my question :)